# Why is "jewel-bright" not found in the dictionaries?

Tags: word-meaning, dictionaries

Why can I not find "jewel-bright" in the dictionaries? Is it a set phrase? The meaning is as bright as a jewel, isn't it?

The context wherein I found it:

> Twenty minutes later, they left Eeylops Owl Emporium, which had been
>   dark and full of rustling and flickering, **jewel-bright** eyes. Harry now
>   carried a large cage that held a beautiful snowy owl, fast asleep with
>   her head under her wing. He couldn't stop stammering his thanks,
>   sounding just like Professor Quirrell.

Answer (score 2):

It's a word the writer invented for that story. It's not a common word. The meaning seems plain enough -- bright like or as a jewel. People invent compound words like that all the time. You wouldn't normally find them in a dictionary.

Comment: Then can I invent a word such as "gold-bright"?

Comment: Absolutely. People do that all the time.